# What's the difference between Dataframe.agg(f) and Dataframe.agg('f')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9],
                   ],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

If I want to sum each column
`df.agg([sum])`and `df.agg(['sum'])` produce the same result.

But if I use np.sum, then only`df.agg([np.sum])` works

`df.agg(['np.sum'])` would raise an `AttributeError: 'np.sum' is not a valid function for 'Series' object`

When using mean function, only `df.agg(['mean'])` works

`df.agg([mean])` would raise `NameError: name 'mean' is not defined`

So my guess is that `agg('f')` is actually a call of method,`Series.f()`
And `agg(f)` is a call of function, `f(Series)`.

But I cannot find specific explanation in Documents. I don't know if I understand it right.

Comment: "But I cannot find specific explanation in Documents" Really? Is [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) the documentation you are reading? If not, why not? If it is, do you see the part where it says "Accepted combinations are:", describing the `func` parameter? Do you understand that part? Why or why not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question either boils down to a fundamental misunderstanding of the language (covered by any tutorial right at the beginning), or else is more than adequately answered by the documentation (Stack Overflow is not tech support). It's not entirely clear which, although I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 1):

`np.sum` isn't a pandas function... It's a numpy function... Therefore the `agg` parameter isn't using `eval`... It's using `getattr` for pandas methods... But `mean` is a pandas function but `np.mean` isn't.

As in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

> Accepted combinations are:
>
> - function
> - **string function name**
> - list of functions and/or function names, e.g. [np.sum, 'mean']
> - dict of axis labels -> functions, function names or list of such.

As you can see, it says `string function name`, which refers to a pandas function name.